# Using power series to evaluate a limit

Tags: limits, power-series

If we want to evaluate the limit of $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1-8x)+8x+32x^2}{3x^2}$$

I would imagine we need to use the power series expansion of the function $${\ln(1-8x)}$$

and then determine what cancels out.

The correct answer that I found using a calculator is $${-512/9}$$

Comment: That's a fine approach indeed.

Comment: You can use L'Hôpital's rule too( $\frac{0}{0}$ form )

Comment: Yes, if you have to follow the assignment, then divide the function into Taylor's series.

Comment: substitute $t=1-8x$ and then L' Hospital. The limit should be $0$ .

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1-8x)+8x+32x^2}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1-8x)}{3x^2}+\frac{8}{3x}+\frac{32}{3}$$

$$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots-\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\ln(1-8x)=-8x-\frac{64x^2}{2}-\frac{512x^3}{3}-\cdots-\frac{8^nx^n}{n}$$
$$\frac{\ln(1-8x)}{3x^2}=-\frac{8}{3x}-\frac{32}{3}-\frac{512x}{9}-\cdots-\frac{8^nx^{n-2}}{3n}$$
$$\frac{\ln(1-8x)}{3x^2}+\frac{8}{3x}+\frac{32}{3}=-\frac{512x}{9}-\cdots-\frac{8^nx^{n-2}}{3n}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1-8x)}{3x^2}+\frac{8}{3x}+\frac{32}{3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(-\frac{512x}{9}-\cdots-\frac{8^nx^{n-2}}{3n}\right)=0$$